# Can I use interlocked classes set 2 variables in a multithreaded env

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm new to programming/C# and have a question..

I have multiple threads reading from files (1 thread/file) on a multicore/cpu machine. A file can contain either ticks(bid/ask info,etc) or bars(open,high,low,close,vol). I have a worker class, which is the target of the thread doWork, which reads the file. A worker / thread can only read either bars or ticks, not both, that is 1 file will be all bars, or all ticks, etc..  Each thread reads the ticks or bars into its own buffer.

I don't use generics or inheritance for performance reasons(I'll probably implement both and test performance). I use a ringbuffer (only 1 read/1writer thread per buffer so this is safe). I also instead check the type of worker to determine if I have a tick or bar.

What I want to do is then process a tick or bar in order by time.. So when a worker adds a bar/tick to its buffer, I want it to get the time and compare to a global mintime, and if it's less, then set the global mintime and set the global index variable so the main thread will know which index to use in its list to get the data in order.

Do I have to lock (I avoid locking using a ringbuffer) or use the interlocked class somehow in both the main and worker?

Code below is pseudocode so not fully correct, but hopefully you get the idea. I'm looking for the best way performance wise.

In my current implementation, before I call GetTick or GetBar in Main, I call NextTime on every simworker in a loop and then sort an array in the main worker list. I think keeping track in the worker thread itself will be more  efficient, just not sure about synchronization. Maybe having to synchronize will erase any benefit.

Pseudocode EX:

```
Main()
{
 List<worker>  workers = new List<worker>;
 workers.Add(new worker(0,TICK));
 workers.Add(new worker(1,BAR));
 workers.Add(new worker(2,TICK));
 workers.Add(new worker(3,BAR)); //etcc, etc.. I do this in a loop.
 //also start all workers - RunAsync.. then.
 while(isrunning)
 {
   if(workers[index].workerType == TICK)
   {
      Tick= workers[index].GetTick();
      //process tick..
   } 
   else 
   {
      Bar b = workers[index].GetBar();
       //process bar..
   }
 }
}

public long mintime;    
public int index;


class worker : BackgroundWorker 
{
  RingBuffer<tick> trb
  RingBuffer<bar> brb
 int idx;
 public type workerType;
 worker(int i, type wtype)
 { idx = i; workerType = wtype } 

 doWork()
 {while(reader.NextData) ;} //calls callback..

 callback(tick t) { trb.add(t); if(t.time < mintime) { mintime=t.time; index= idx}//???
 callback(bar b){   brb.add(b); if(b.time < mintime) { mintime=b.time; index =idx}
 Tick GetTick() { trb.Read();}
 Bar GetBar() {brb.Read();{
}
```

Comment: I may be ignorant but what guarantees the thread-safety of your ring buffer? You're reading / writing the buffer in each thread based on your example: someone is calling `callback` and the main thread is calling `GetXxxx`. What guarantees that a BAR / TICK doesn't get overwritten while it's being processed on the main thread?

Answer (score 4):

If you are concerned about performance you should redesign your code.

The fact that you machine is multicore doesn't mean that your reads are faster. They are not. In fact, if you do it this way your reads become slower, purely because there is one file and many threads that want to read different chunks. You may get faster performance if your disk is a mirrored RAID array. Otherwise multithreaded reads will degrade performance, as multiple threads will compete for the unique file access.

So you better design a single producer (a thread that reads a chunk into memory) and multiple consumers (threads that read shared memory and do crunching).

Side note

> I don't use generics or inheritance for performance reasons

This is just silly. Generics were designed to improve performance. Such code optimisations upfront shall be much avoided. Inheritance doesn't degrade performance on the scale you should care about.

Comment: I thought he wrote there are multiple files and each thread reads one file.

Comment: @xxbbcc Unless you have multiple hard drives, there is only one head on the disk.  It can only be reading one file at a time.  Either one thread will be blocking while the other is being read, or worse yet, the disk head will be constantly moving back and forth between the two files, *dramatically* harming performance.  If the files are on completely different hard drives, then you can actually gain something from parallel reads.

Comment: @Servy I know but it's not necessarily true that parallel reads will be always slower. Whenever I implemented parallel reads (over multiple files, not a single file), it always came out faster than reading input files on a single thread (using HDDs, not SSDs).

Comment: @xxbbcc Such a thing is very hard to test though.  Odds are you were either: 1) don't some non-trivail amount of non-UI work as well in your tests, getting the benefit of that in parallel 2) Reading in files that were already cached by the OS, which can be effectively read in parallel.  #2 is probably more likely in a contrived stress test, #1 is more likely if it's behavior you observed in a "real" application.

Comment: Good point about the drive. I do only have 1 drive, though I do plan on adding another. I will probably change the implementation to create a thread/drive.  That still leaves the issue of locking/synchonizing. What's the best way to do that ?

Comment: @Servy You could be right, I didn't run rigorous tests to prove performance gains. And yes, the threads were doing other work, too, not just reading the files.

Comment: @xxbbcc  Each RingBuffer is only read by 1 thread and written to by 1 thread, so it is safe to use.  Each worker has it's own ringbuffer.  RingBuffers can be safely used wihtout locking assuming only 1reader/1writer. Sacrifice memory/performance..

Comment: I thought about using inheritance, but I only have and will only ever have 2 types to care about, so thought it was unnecessary, especially since it is slower.  Ultimately the user of this code is a genetic optimizer, and the processor or the ticks/bars is a trading strategy.  So optimizing many parameters,with large ranges, over N securities is a very large task. Any performance gain I can get I'll take.